# justified nested button group in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, buttongroup

I am having a Button group control like this.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div role="group" class="d-flex btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
       <div role="group" class="dropdown btn-group">
          <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></button>
          <div aria-labelledby="" class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 32px, 0px);"><a class="w-100 dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Dropdown link</a><a class="w-100 dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Dropdown link</a></div>
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button><button title="Clear" type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></button>
    </div>
```

The nested button group is not taking the available width as other buttons are taking.

I tried giving `w-100` as well but no help.

Comment: adding `w-100` to the dropdown works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, its may help you

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
 .btn-group .col-6-cus { width:50% !important;}
 .btn-group .col-6-cus .dropdown-toggle { width:100%;}
</style>

</head>

<body>


    <div role="group" class="d-flex btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="w-100 col-6-cus btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
       <div role="group" class="dropdown btn-group col-6-cus">
          <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-download"></i></button>
          <div aria-labelledby="" class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 32px, 0px);"><a class="w-100 dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Dropdown link</a><a class="w-100 dropdown-item" role="button" href="#">Dropdown link</a></div>
       </div>
       <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-outline-secondary col-6-cus"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>
       <button title="Clear" type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-outline-secondary col-6-cus"><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. I was able to fix it by adding the `flex-fill` class to the div of the nested button group.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style></style>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

      <div class="btn-group w-100" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-25"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></button>
   

   <div class="btn-group w-25" role="group">
     <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle w-100" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-25"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-25"><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></button>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I want it to take up all available width. The example provided by you doesn't take up whole width

Comment: @rahul - pls check above editted snippet. and pls removed down vote.